# Nested json in Highcharts Stacked

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I googled allot about the nested json for Highcharts [stacked percentage column](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-percent), but dint get the proper out out.

Here's the code which I tried but dint get the proper output.

can anyone help me out in sorting what mistake am doing ?

thanks in advance.

```js
$(function () {
  var processed_json = new Array();
  $.getJSON('javascripts/data.json', function(data) {
    // Populate series
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      processed_json.push([data[i].key, data[i].value]);
    }
    // draw chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
      chart: {
        type: "bar"
      },
      title: {
        text: "Student data"
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
          text: ""
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: "Scores"
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          stacking: 'normal'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Subjects',
        data: processed_json,
      }]
    });
  });
});

// this is how am displaying in data.json

[
  {"key":"john","value":[34,53,45,45,98]},
  {"key":"Rita","value":[98,34,43,54,66,66]},
  {"key":"james","value":[91,33,45,65,65,38]},
  {"key":"jade","value":[98,54,54,45,45,45]},
  {"key":"lara","value":[23,23,98,23,23,23]} 
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Comment: And how your output (processed_json) looks before you are adding it to your chart? Do you have numbers, or strings in your y values? You may try parsing your values to Int before you will add them to your array

Comment: thanks for suggestion @GrzegorzBlachliński, my background is CSS/HTML, I don't know how to pass an array

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `processed_json` is not formatted in a way that Highcharts API can process.

Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/jo8foxtz/

Here's the code:

```js
$(function() {

  var processed_json = new Array();
  
  data = [{
    "key": "john",
    "value": [34, 53, 45, 45, 98]
  }, {
    "key": "Rita",
    "value": [98, 34, 43, 54, 66, 66]
  }, {
    "key": "james",
    "value": [91, 33, 45, 65, 65, 38]
  }, {
    "key": "jade",
    "value": [98, 54, 54, 45, 45, 45]
  }, {
    "key": "lara",
    "value": [23, 23, 98, 23, 23, 23]
  }];

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = {};
    item["name"] = data[i].key;
    item["data"] = data[i].value;
    processed_json.push(item);
  }


  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Student data'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      allowDecimals: false,
      title: {
        text: ""
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: 'Scores'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
      shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        stacking: 'percent'
      }
    },
    series: processed_json
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruvan Ganesh, but I want to call the `json` file from outside, can you send me the only codes which should be in `html` and `json`.

@CSKAdmin

Comment: I have pointed out where you were deviating from the API docs which I believe answers your question. If you want access JSON via an external API try JSONP or CORS. If you want internally hosted docs try jQuery.getJSON. If you want the code in HTML use <script> tags to include the JS code inline.

Comment: can you provide any link ? @dhruvan Ganesh

Comment: Sure: [This Sitepoint Page](https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/) will give you a basic explanation on why JSONP or CORS is a good idea.